# Need help in extracting data from csv and writing to a text file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv with two columns of data. I want to extract data from one column and write to a text file with single-quote on each element and separated by a comma. For example, I have this..

```
taxable_entity_id,id
45efc167-9254-406c-b5a8-6aef91a73dd9,331999
5ae97680-f489-4182-9dcb-eb07a73fab15,103507
00018d93-ae71-4367-a0da-f252cea4dfa2,32991
```

I want all the taxable_entity_ids in a text file like this

```
'45efc167-9254-406c-b5a8-6aef91a73dd9','5ae97680-f489-4182-9dcb-eb07a73fab15','00018d93-ae71-4367-a0da-f252cea4dfa2'
```

without any space between two elements, separated by a comma.

Edit:

This is what i tried..

```
import csv


with open("Taxable_entity_those_who_filed_G1_M_July_but_not_in_Aug.csv", 'r') as csv_File:

    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_File)

    with open("te_id.csv", 'w') as text_file:
        writer = csv.writer(text_file, quotechar='\'', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row["taxable_entity_id"])
            # print(row["taxable_entity_id"])

    text_file.close()

csv_File.close()
```

and this is what I got..

```
4,5,e,f,c,1,6,7,-,9,2,5,4,-,4,0,6,c,-,b,5,a,8,-,6,a,e,f,9,1,a,7,3,d,d,9
5,a,e,9,7,6,8,0,-,f,4,8,9,-,4,1,8,2,-,9,d,c,b,-,e,b,0,7,a,7,3,f,a,b,1,5
0,0,0,1,8,d,9,3,-,a,e,7,1,-,4,3,6,7,-,a,0,d,a,-,f,2,5,2,c,e,a,4,d,f,a,2
```

Comment: What you tried and what was the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. Simply as you want one single line in the output file, you should write it at once by using a comprehension:

```
import csv


with open("Taxable_entity_those_who_filed_G1_M_July_but_not_in_Aug.csv", 'r') as csv_File:

    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_File)

    with open("te_id.csv", 'w') as text_file:
        # use QUOTE_ALL to force the quoting
        writer = csv.writer(text_file, quotechar='\'', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        writer.writerow((row["taxable_entity_id"] for row in reader))
```

And do not use `close` as you have (correctly) used `with`.

Answer (score 1):

try that

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('nameoffile.csv',delimiter = ',')
X = df[0].values
f = open('newfile.txt','w')
for i in X:
    f.write(X[i] + ',')
f.close()
```

Comment: Pandas is very nice and powerful tool, but a bit overkill here... And please use `join` instead of your rather ugly loop that will add an ending comma.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems a little odd that you basically want a one row csv file for the `taxable_entity_ids`, but certain possible. You also don't need to explicitly `close()` the open files because the `with` context manager will do it for you automatically.

You also need to open the CSV file with `newline=''` as shown in all the examples in the `csv` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv).

Lastly, if you want the all the fields to be quoted you need to use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` instead of `quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`.

```
import csv


inp_filename = "Taxable_entity_those_who_filed_G1_M_July_but_not_in_Aug.csv"
outp_filename = "te_id.csv"

with open(outp_filename, 'w', newline='') as text_file, \
     open(inp_filename, 'r', newline='') as csv_File:

    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_File)
    writer = csv.writer(text_file, quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    taxable_entity_ids = (row["taxable_entity_id"] for row in reader)
    writer.writerow(taxable_entity_ids)

print('done')
```